# How to make this marquee style css take up the whole page?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner to html/css and would like to get this code to fit my requirements.

I am displaying an image that is scrolling using css, the height of which is 1920 and the width of which is 6469. I want to display it in portrait mode, and I want the image to take up the entire screen. It is important to note that I want to display this in a 1080 by 1920 area, without having a scroll bar on the window. Here is my current code.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.scrolling {
  animation: marquee 25s linear infinite;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scrolling">
      <img src="Sports_Background_3_proper2.png" height="1920">
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling" aria-hidden="true">
      <img src="Sports_Background_3_proper2.png" height="1920">
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling" aria-hidden="true">
      <img src="Sports_Background_3_proper2.png" height="1920">
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling" aria-hidden="true">
      <img src="Sports_Background_3_proper2.png" height="1920">
    </div>
    <!-- … -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```
````

obviously I have no code in the css to make the image take up the whole screen, but I had tried so many things that my code got very muddy. There must be a proper way to do this so I took out all of my failed attempts

Comment: Your stylesheet link needs to go in [head tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)

Comment: how should an image take up 1080px in width take up the exact width of a screen withotu overflow if the screen itself is not exactly 1080p wide?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to expand the image to the full vierport using:

```
img {height:100vh;}
```